# Tool for analyzing lucene index

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a Solr application which stores lots of fields.
I want to reduce the Lucene index size.
For that I want to analyze how much does each field takes out of the total index file.
Are there any tools for this task?
I've tried Luke which is very handful, but didn't see these specific details.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be possible. See [here](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-solr-user/201601.mbox/%3CCA+B7dji9dKujk7w-Avg_s9h1Mjr+0VrzXSPX9Y3C1iL-ur4QqQ@mail.gmail.com%3E)